# container function origin in Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

i am new to jenkins and I see in my Jenkinsfile `container('docker')`. I am not sure if this is something built into jenkins, jenkins plugin, or something custom to my company. How can I findout/debug where it came from? At the top of my `Jenkinsfile` I see `@Library('com-shared-lib') _` so I assume things are coming from this lib but I am not sure what.

Jenkinsfile

```
@Library('msaas-shared-lib') _

pipeline {
  stages {
    stage('BUILD') {
      when { anyOf { branch 'master'; changeRequest() } }
      stages {
        stage('Docker Multi Stage Build') {
          steps {
            container('docker') {
              // some docker commands
              // ...
              // ...
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like [`container`](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/kubernetes/#container-run-build-steps-in-a-container) step from [Kubernetes Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/kubernetes/).